# Python re sub два раза

Tags: python, sqlite, re

требуется удалять во всех строчках списка, лишние символы.

```
print("Введите полную ссылку к txt файлу, например D:\\Codding\\Work\\Python ")
Ab = input("Введите сюда ")

con = sqlite3.connect("D:\\Codding\\Work\\Python\Works\\Bot for searching\\base.bd")
curs = con.cursor()
blb = open(Ab, 'r', encoding='utf-8')

file_data = [re.sub('[()]', '', i).strip('\n').split(';') for i in blb]



curs.executemany('INSERT INTO dann_Vk VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', file_data )
con.commit()
print("Успешно")
```

Код прекрасно работает. 
Как его модифицировать, чтобы выполнялось 2 раза re.sub, то есть удалялись и скобки, и пробел, и "-"?
Спасибо!

Comment: в каком месте здесь удаляется пробел и "-"?

Comment: Просто замените '[()]' на '[()\s-]'

Comment: MaxU, А если пробел, то просто '[()\s \s-]' ??

Comment: @Vlad, `"\s"` - в RegEx отвечает за пробел и табуляцию

Comment: Спасибо большое!